# IOS Codenameone apps error on Build Server everytime 'symbol: variable Display'

Tags: codenameone

Since a few hours ago, everytime i submit an IOS build to the CN1 build server, it errors. Even for apps which i have not changed and build fine 2 days ago. Android builds are fine. Please can you resolve.
Thanks
The bottom of the error log has:

```
    Executing: javac -classpath /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/classes -d /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/classes /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java /var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
        Display.getInstance().setProperty("build_key", d(BUILD_KEY));
        ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:23: error: cannot find symbol
        Display.getInstance().setProperty("package_name", PACKAGE_NAME);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
        Display.getInstance().setProperty("built_by_user", d(BUILT_BY_USER));
        ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
        Display.getInstance().setProperty("AppVersion", APPLICATION_VERSION);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:26: error: cannot find symbol
        Display.getInstance().setProperty("AppName", APPLICATION_NAME);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:27: error: cannot find symbol
        Display.getInstance().setProperty("iosNewStorage", "true");
        ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:50: error: cannot find symbol
                    r.addArgument("v", Display.getInstance().getProperty("AppVersion", "0.1"));
                                       ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:51: error: cannot find symbol
                    r.addArgument("pl", Display.getInstance().getPlatformName());
                                        ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:63: error: cannot find symbol
        Display.getInstance().callSerially(new Runnable() { 
        ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:73: error: cannot find symbol
             Display.getInstance().callSerially(this);         }
             ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
/var/folders/zh/kb_4hqhn4kg1h0r5dp_6htcm0000gn/T/build8196920828988636221xxx/stub/PocketMoneyStub.java:99: error: cannot find symbol
        Display.init(stub);
        ^
  symbol:   variable Display
  location: class PocketMoneyStub
11 errors
Process return code is 1
```

Answer (score 0):

CN1 did a redeployment, on their end, and all is working now. Thanks